# Choosing Template to develop iphone project

Tags: iphone

I have 11 Pages so i want to navigate to any page from any current page with good memory management...so which template i use to develop ...

Thanks...

Comment: sounds like ab TabBar, cause you want to navigate from every Page to all others. But don't know if you can add 11 TabItems on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TabBar template, but when you add 11 pages it will create a more button.